# Filter returned XML element's

Tags: java, xml, filter, element

I've created a method which returns the contents of a particular XML element. The list returned is as follows:

```
data/13-Apr-2017-17:08:46-usage
archive/13-Apr-2017-17:08:58-usage
data/13-Apr-2017-17:09:04-usage
data/13-Apr-2017-17:11:47-bandwidth
archive/13-Apr-2017-17:11:47-operation
archive/13-Apr-2017-18:42:05-bandwidth
data/13-Apr-2017-18:42:05-operation
archive/14-Apr-2017-09:57:18-usage
debug/14-Apr-2017-13:45:46-usage
```

How do I then filter this to only return elements that begin with data, and contain the text usage? A further step might be to only return the value with the most recent date/time.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I think I got it. Something along these lines:

```
if(eElement.getElementsByTagName("Key").item(0).getTextContent().startsWith("data")){
    System.out.println("Key: " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("Key").item(0).getTextContent());
}
```

I've a few other bits to work out but should get it from here.